# A stack-based language interpreter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, interpreter

Here is a little interpreter I wrote for a simple stack-based language. It is my first attempt at a complete Haskell program, beyond glorified calculator use.

I'd like very much to get an expert's opinon on stylistic matters.

Also, although the thing runs fine, on a test program it seems to suffer from a space leak: I see an increasing amount of Map objects in Drag state, at one particular spot in the code (where the SCC "store1" directive is). I don't understand why the insert step would not free the old Map version. Also, retainer profiling blames the "arry" lens, which is not even used in this piece of code, and uses an IntMap, not a Map. I don't understand what is going on...

EDIT: whoops. I was using the sieve of Eratosthenes as a test program for my interpreter, so it is probably normal that the IntMap usage grows linearily in time..

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Mango where

import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<$), (<*>), (<*))
import Control.Category
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Data.Bits
import Data.Char (chr,ord)
import Data.IntMap.Strict as IM hiding (null)
import Data.Lens
import Data.Lens.Template
import Data.Map.Strict as M hiding (null)
import Data.Maybe
import Prelude hiding ((.))
import Text.Parsec hiding (label)
import Text.Parsec.Char

---------------
-- Utility code

(??) t _ True  = t
(??) _ f False = f

io = liftIO

a !!= b = (a != b) >> return ()

-- Lens for array items
item :: Integer -> Lens (IntMap v) v
item idx = lens (IM.! (fromInteger idx)) (IM.insert (fromInteger idx))


----------
-- PARSING

type ProgPtr = [Tok]
data Tok = Label String
         | Number Integer
         | Keyword String       
     deriving Show


comment = (string "/*" >> in_comment) <?> "comment"
voidChar = () <$ anyChar
in_comment =  (try (string "*/") >> return ())
          <|> ((comment <|> voidChar) >> in_comment) 
          <?> "end of comment"

whitespace = many1 (() <$ space  <|> comment )

tchar = oneOf $ '_' : ['a'..'z']

tok =  Number . read <$> many1 digit
   <|> do
    ident <- many1 tchar
    (char ':' >> return (Label ident)) 
                 <|> return (Keyword ident)
   <?> "token"

-- eof here chokes on trailing garbage, but prevents single-pass parsing
program = optional whitespace >> (tok `sepEndBy1` whitespace) <* eof

------------
-- Compiling

-- find all labels, will use them as variables later
allLabels = M.fromList . allLabels' where
        allLabels' [] = []
        allLabels' (Label l : xs) = (l, PtrVal xs) : allLabels' xs
        allLabels' (_ : xs) = allLabels' xs

------------
-- Execution

data Value = IntVal Integer | PtrVal ProgPtr

{- Stack values contain both a value and an optional variable symbol.
 - This is to get around a language quirk, the "magical" semantics
 - of 'store' which operates on the name of the last variable pushed
 - instead of on its content. This seemed a more robust approach
 - than looking ahead for a 'store' token in the parser to distinguish
 - symbols from values.
 -}
newtype Stack = Stack { unStack :: (Maybe String, Value) }

instance Show Stack where
    show (Stack (Nothing, v)) = show v
    show (Stack (Just var, v)) = "<" ++ var ++ ">" ++ show v

instance Show Value where
    show (IntVal n) = show n
    show (PtrVal _) = "<pointer>"

data ProgState = ProgState {
        _stack :: [Stack],
        _vars  :: Map String Value,
        _arry  :: IntMap Value,
        _ip    :: ProgPtr
} deriving Show

$( makeLenses [''ProgState] )

type MangoT m a = StateT ProgState (ErrorT String m) a

initProg p = ProgState
    []               -- empty stack at startup
    (allLabels p)    -- first convert all labels as pointer variables 
    IM.empty            -- empty array
    p                -- full program as initial IP

exit = (ip !!= [])
dump :: MangoT IO ()
dump = (get >>= io.print)
crash reason = (io.print) reason >> dump >> exit
m <!> r = catchError m (const $ throwError r)

push = (>> return ()) . (stack %=) . (:) . Stack 
pushi x = push (Nothing, IntVal x)

ucons (h:t) = (h,t)

pop  = unStack <$> (stack !%%= ucons)
popi = do { (_, IntVal v) <- pop; return v } <!> "Cannot pop required int"
popp = do { (_, PtrVal p) <- pop; return p } <!> "Cannot pop required ptr"
pops = do { (Just s, _) <- pop; return s } <!> "Cannot pop symbol"

binop f = do { y <- popi; x <- popi; pushi (x `f` y) }

cjump test = do
    no <- popp
    yes <- popp
    x <- popi
    if test x
        then ip !!= yes
        else ip !!= no

-- Execution of a single operand

exec (Label _)  = return () 
exec (Number n) = pushi n
exec (Keyword "add") = binop (+)
exec (Keyword "call") = do
        tgt <- popp
        cur <- access ip
        push (Nothing, PtrVal cur)
        ip !!= tgt
exec (Keyword "dup") = do { x <- pop; push x; push x }
exec (Keyword "exit") = exit
exec (Keyword "ifz") = cjump (== 0)
exec (Keyword "ifg") = cjump (> 0)
exec (Keyword "jump") = popp >>= (ip !!=)
exec (Keyword "mod") = binop mod
exec (Keyword "print_byte") = popi >>= io.putChar.chr.fromInteger
exec (Keyword "print_num") = popi >>= io.putStr.show
exec (Keyword "read_num") = io readLn >>= pushi
exec (Keyword "read_byte") = io getChar >>= pushi.toInteger.ord

exec (Keyword "store") = {-# SCC "store1" #-} do
        addr <- pops
        (_, n) <- pop
        vars !%= M.insert addr n
        return ()
exec (Keyword "sub") = binop (-)
exec (Keyword "vload") = do
        i <- popi
        x <- access (item i . arry)
        push (Nothing,x)
        return ()
exec (Keyword "vstore") = do
        (_,x) <- pop
        idx <- popi
        (item idx . arry) !!= x
exec (Keyword "xor") = binop xor

exec (Keyword k) = do
        vs <- access vars
        push (Just k, fromMaybe (IntVal 0) (M.lookup k vs))

fetch = ip !%%= ucons

step = catchError (fetch >>= exec) crash

dumpLens l = access l >>= (io . print)

terminated = null <$> access ip

loop step = step >> (terminated >>= (return () ?? loop step))

runProgWith step p = evalStateT (loop step) (initProg p)

runProgram = runProgWith step 

onLeft _ (Right x) = Right x
onLeft f (Left x) = Left (f x)

wrapError = mapErrorT (fmap (onLeft show))

withErrors m = do
        r <- runErrorT m
        case r of
                Right _ -> return ()
                Left err -> fail err

decodeArgs [file]      = return (file, runProgram)
decodeArgs ["-d",file] = return (file, debugProgram)
decodeArgs _           = fail "Usage: hango [-d] file.mango"


main = withErrors $ do
        (file,run) <- io getArgs >>= decodeArgs
        prog <- wrapError . ErrorT $ parseFromFile program file
        run prog
```

Answer (score 6):

- Name of `Stack` type is misleading, you mean *Stack element*
  (`StackElt`), not a whole stack.
- Same for `withErrors`. *withX* is
  usually reserved for two or more argument function, such that the
  last argument is function taking argument of type`X`, e.g. `\x :: X
  -> ...` Did you mean `handleErrors`?
- Did you really mean that value of an error is an error message? Or did you
  rather intend to display
  error and go on with execution? (This is not clear from code. One
  should insert comment whenever intention of code is not apparent, or
  just complicated.)
- Did you use `hlint` on this code?

Comment: Further, there is a lack of types on functions. They often help a new reader understand things.